# Use encrypted connection on mySQL server[C#]

Tags: c#, mysql, ssl

I created a chat recently on C#. What it does is that uses mySQL parameterized queries to upload the message from the user to the server. Then the other clients download this message to their "screen".

Now my question is this. Do i have to use SSL to encrypt the connection ? And if yes, how i can do that ? Everything i found online is completely confusing for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do encryption in your app one (or both) levels:

- Transport layer: by using SSL (HTTPS): this is easy to do and ready-made. See [this](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/06/22/setting-up-mysql-ssl-and-secure-connections/), for example.
- Application layer: you encrypt your messages in your application manually using some library, and you send the messages encrypted (to the database or the other client). There are a lot of possibilities here (algorithm, library, ...)

You can do both: crypt your messages manually and send them using SSL.

Comment: Do you know if i can install an SSL certificate to my mySQL database through phpmyadmin ? I am asking that... because i have a database ona hosting site... and i can access it only through phpmyadmin.

Comment: No you can't. But the hosting service usually offer you some kind of file management interface that you can use to upload the certificate file.